# Django Many-to-many query fulfilling a specific condition

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have these two models

```
class Genre( TimeStampAwareModel ):
   genre = models.CharField ( max_length = 255, blank = False )
   parent = models.ForeignKey ( 'self', null=True, blank=True, related_name = "childs" )
   ..
class Track( TimeStampAwareModel ):
   ....
   genre = models.ManyToManyField( Genre )
```

I have as input list of genres [Pop,Rock,..], since Pop and Rock have child genres too. Now i want to filter all tracks fulfilling following condition

**(G1parent OR G1child1 OR G1child2 OR .....) AND (G2parent OR G2child1 OR G2child2 OR .....)**

```
def get_genre_tracks(list_genre):
   ....
   ...
   return tracks
```

here G1parent is Pop and G2parent is Rock, How can i get this? looking for an elegant solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you want all tracks that either have a genre of "Rock" *or* a genre that has "Rock" as a parent. If so:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Track.objects.filter(Q(genre__genre='Rock') | Q(genre__parent__genre='Rock')).distinct()
```

**EDIT**

Actually, after re-reading the question it seems you want what I said, but for a list of genres together, instead of just one at a time. For that, you just need to tweak the above code like:

```
Track.objects.filter(Q(genre__genre__in=['Rock', 'Pop']) | Q(genre__parent__genre__in=['Rock', 'Pop'])).distinct()
```

**UPDATE**

Ah, then it's a bit more complicated but still doable.

```
has_rock_genres = Q(genre__genre='Rock') | Q(genre__parent__genre='Rock')
has_pop_genres = Q(genre__genre='Pop') | Q(genre__parent__genre='Pop')

Track.objects.filter(has_rock_genres & has_pop_genres).distinct()
```

You could do that all in one line, but the code becomes a bit of a mess at that point.

**UPDATE**

Really giving me a mental workout today, aren't you? ;)

You'll need to do something like:

```
query = None
for genre in genres:
    if query is None:
        query = Q(genre__genre=genre) | Q(genre__parent__genre=genre)
    else:
        query = query & (Q(genre__genre=genre) | Q(genre__parent__genre=genre))

    Track.objects.filter(query).distinct()
```

Comment: No, i want all tracks that have Rock or its child genre And Pop or child genre? hope you understand my question

Comment: `genre__genre__in=['Rock', 'Pop']` will get all tracks have either Rock OR Pop but i want AND relation

Comment: I want the exact as in your last edit, but i have list of parent genres. How can i do this in one line please?

Comment: its been 11 hours working and I was out of my mind, you made my job easy Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Chris Pratt
Nice solution but there is a small glitch.
Using `query & Q(genre__genre=genre) ` will not compare fields with other rows in the table but rather with the same row against itself and the result would be empty. You should use `q = q.filter(Q(genre__genre=genre))` instead

Comment: @Irfan: Sorry, but you're incorrect. I have used code like this in my own projects and it works flawlessly. Perhaps you've misunderstood the code? Regardless, it works.